# tkinter python: How can I put radios in the left and the button on center?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How can I put radios in the left and the button on center ?
I put radio on the left. and center is the default. Right ?
But it doesn't work.

[image]

```
def sel():
   selection = "You selected the option " + str(var.get())

root = Tk()
var = IntVar()
frame=Frame(root)
R1 = Radiobutton(frame, text="Option 1", variable=var, value=1,
                  command=sel)
R1.pack(side=LEFT)

R2 = Radiobutton(frame, text="Option 2", variable=var, value=2,
                  command=sel)
R2.pack(side=LEFT)


btn_refresh = Button(frame, text="Refresh Data",
                     command=sel)

frame.pack()
btn_refresh.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Wanted:
[image]

Comment: Why not use `.grid` instead of `.pack`? I think it might be easier to implement it that way. Also can you please use paint or something similar to show us exactly what you are after?

Comment: Can you give an example ? @TheLizzard

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is RadioButton R2 parent is root, it must be frame.
The second one is frame must fill root, else everything will be squished together.

The below modified code will work.

```
def sel():
   selection = "You selected the option " + str(var.get())

root = Tk()
var = IntVar()
frame=Frame(root)

R1 = Radiobutton(frame, text="Option 1", variable=var, value=1, command=sel)
R1.pack(side=LEFT, anchor='w')
R2 = Radiobutton(frame, text="Option 2", variable=var, value=2, command=sel)
R2.pack(side=LEFT, anchor='w')

btn_refresh = Button(frame, text="Refresh Data", command=sel)
btn_refresh.pack()

frame.pack(fill=X)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: But the button is not in central. @Harxish

Comment: It will be in the center. Where does the button appear for you ?

Comment: Between Centeral and Right @Harxish

Answer (score 0):

If you want the button centered between radio buttons then just rearrange the order of widget creation and make the second radiobutton packed to the right.

```py
def sel():
   selection = "You selected the option " + str(var.get())

root = Tk()
var = IntVar()
frame=Frame(root)
R1 = Radiobutton(frame, text="Option 1", variable=var, value=1,
                  command=sel)
R1.pack(side=LEFT)

btn_refresh = Button(frame, text="Refresh Data",
                     command=sel)

R2 = Radiobutton(frame, text="Option 2", variable=var, value=2,
                  command=sel)
R2.pack(side=RIGHT)

frame.pack()
btn_refresh.pack()

root.mainloop()
```